# How to set UI Text To A Different UI Text in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm trying to make a level complete screen that will show your level finish time when I turn on the EndScreenScript.

The Timer Script:

```
public class TimerScript : MonoBehaviour{

public Text timerText;
private float startTime;


void Start() {
    startTime = Time.time;
}

public void Update(){
    float t = Time.time - startTime;

    string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
    string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

    timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds; 
}
}
```

Here is my End Screen Time code:

```
public class EndScreenScript : MonoBehaviour{

public Text endScreenTime;
public TimerScript TimerScript;

void Awake()  {
    endScreenTime = TimerScript.timerText;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Could you specify what your desired behaviour vs the actual behaviour is?

Comment: @Armin i want the endScreenTime To display the TimerScript.timerText when i activate the endScreenTime

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `endScreenTime` to display the `timerText` when you activate the object, you need to use

```
void OnEnable()
```

opposed to

```
void Awake()
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) here

"Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded."

"OnEnable is called when the object becomes enabled and active."